# Is it possible to uniquely find the shape of a curve using the tensorial formula of curve length?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, curves

According to the formula below

$$L = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{\Biggl|\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}g_{ij}(\gamma(t))\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}x^{i}\circ\gamma(t)\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}x^{j}\circ\gamma(t)\Bigr)\Biggr|}\mathrm{d}t,$$

one can compute the length of a curve $\gamma(t)$ between $t = a$ and $t=b$ having a metric $g_{ij}$. Under what necessary and/or sufficient one can do the inverse? I mean, having the length of the curve, interval $[a,b]$, and metric $g_{ij}$, how can we yield $\gamma(t)$?

Comment: Can you find the curve $\gamma$ joining north to south in sphere with induced metric?

Comment: @C.F.G: I don't know whether the resulting integral equation can be solved.

Comment: I didn't asked you to solve any equation. I asked you, think about 2-sphere. now find (visually) the curve 
$\gamma$
 joining north to south in sphere with induced metric

Comment: Stop and think here. Take $\Bbb R^2$. If I tell you a curve starts at the origin and has length $5$, can you determine the curve? Even if I tell you that it's a geodesic, can you determine the curve?